# how to set up SQLite database using capacitor for ionic application with angular?

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic7

I am using the Ionic framework with Angular and Capacitor to build a chat application. I want to implement storage in my application. I am trying to set up an SQLite database for my Capacitor project. The purpose of using SQLite is so that I can store data locally in SQLite database after fetching it from server, so that I can get data even if server does not respond or store previous chat data even when we are offline.
I am using MongoDB in the backend, but the primary database model for SQLite is Relational DBMS. How can I make this work together?

I am hardly able to find any solution for this. Can anyone please guide me with all the steps required to set up SQLite for capacitor project.

Comment: see link below with full example on Ionic Angular: 
https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite/blob/master/docs/Ionic-Angular-Usage.md

Answer (score 0):

[I had a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76904686/can-i-create-an-ionic-app-that-runs-offline-on-a-windows-machine-with-an-sqlite) and managed to set up an SQLite database for my Ionic App using [this example](https://github.com/jepiqueau/ionic7-angular-sqlite-starter/tree/main). The process was a pain though [(not just for me)](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/sqlite-and-capacitor-3/211951). Since you don't seem to need a relational database (you're already using MongoDB), I would recommend letting go of SQLite and using e.g. [Ionic Storage](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage) instead.